# First call to transform() fails with inf, all subsequent calls are OK - what could be the reason?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapely, proj, pyproj

I'm trying to get to the bottom of the following (weird) problem. When applying `pyproj.Transformer` transformation to a certain polygon, it fails the *first* time with `(inf,inf)` throughout. Second and all subsequent calls to the same work just fine!

I saw similar issues with inf which had to do with inappropriate CRS (out of bounds), but this is not the case here.

The question was originally prompted by geopandas' `to_crs()` failing occasionally; [similar question by someone else here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372351/re-projection-from-bng-to-wsg84-consistently-fails-using-geopandas-to-crs).

#### Example

```py
import shapely, shapely.geometry, shapely.speedups, shapely.ops, pyproj
print('Shapely version:',shapely.__version__)
print('Shapely speedups enabled:',shapely.speedups.enabled)
#shapely.speedups.disable() # makes no difference
print('Pyproj version:',pyproj.__version__)
print('PROJ version:',pyproj.proj_version_str)

xy = [(532303, 181814), (532190, 181854), (532192, 181861), (532199, 181863), 
      (532195, 181874), (532183, 181870), (532163, 181864), (532162, 181868), 
      (532309, 181915), (532294, 181828), (532306, 181820)] #, (532303, 181814)]
geom = shapely.geometry.Polygon(xy)
OSGB1936 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:27700')
WGS84 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:4326')

proj = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(OSGB1936, WGS84, always_xy=True)
func = proj.transform

# First call fails with inf, all subsequent calls are OK:
for ii in range(3):
    tp = shapely.ops.transform(func, geom)
    print(tp.exterior.coords[0])
```

#### Output:

> Shapely version: 1.7.1
> Shapely speedups enabled: True
> Pyproj version: 2.6.1.post1
> PROJ version: 7.1.0
> (inf, inf)
> (-0.0929010345368997, 51.519248856167074)
> (-0.0929010345368997, 51.519248856167074)

Comment: Did you install with conda? It could be that you are using PROJ_NETWORK.

Comment: @snowman2: good point, thanks. Yes, installed with conda (from conda-forge channel). Will try setting PROJ_NETWORK to OFF and report back.

Comment: @snowman2 That seems to solve the problem. Even though the `proj.ini` has `network = on` commented out, the `PROJ_NETWORK` is set to `ON`. Setting it to off explicitly works: i.e., `os.environ['PROJ_NETWORK'] = 'OFF'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@snowman2 's comment fixes the problem; viz.: explicitly setting

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_NETWORK'] = 'OFF'
```

in the preamble resolves the issue. Thanks!

Also verified that the original problem is solved (i.e., geopandas' `to_crs()` works fine with or without pygeos)

Comment: This is a useful reference: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/transformation_grids.html