# Why does GeoPandas behave differently on Windows and Linux (and is there a work-around)?

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

I am using Python Geopandas 0.12.2 to read and reproject a shapefile.  My code works on Windows 10 but does not produce the correct results on Linux.  Specifically, the Linux implementation produces a geometry that consists entirely of 'inf' values (see output below).  I have used the same environment.yml file to build the same conda/mamba environment on both systems.  The source shapefile includes a single polygon with crs=EPSG 4269.

To get the correct behavior on Linux I've tried (without success) a handful of interventions aimed at lower-level control using Shapely and PyProj rather than Geopandas; these interventions were informed by the discussions involving PyProj axis order and the 'always_xy' parameter (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480010/python-pyproj-transform-yielding-different-results-for-the-same-input-parameters).
But my prior question is: Should this reprojection command require different implementation or arguments on Linux?

Here is the code:

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj

PROJ4 = "+datum=WGS84 +lat_0=23 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lon_0=-96 +no_defs +proj=aea +units=m +x_0=0 +y_0=0"
crs_to = pyproj.CRS.from_proj4(PROJ4)

# For reproducibility: Generate a sample GeoDataframe from a subset of the 
# coordinates of my actual polygon shapefile
coords = [[-74.051, 42.818], [-74.0496, 42.819], [-74.0495, 42.817], [-74.0495, 42.817], [-74.051, 42.818]]
geojson={"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type":"Feature", "properties":{"id":1},
                                                  "geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[coords]]}}]}

shp_from = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson, crs='EPSG:4269')


shp_to = shp_from.to_crs(crs_to)

print('\nos name: ', os.name)
print('geopandas version: ', gpd.__version__)
print('pyproj version: ', pyproj.__version__)

print('crs_from: ', shp_from.crs)
print('crs_to: ', crs_to)

print('\n\nSource geometry')
print(shp_from.geometry)

print('\n\nTarget geometry')
print(shp_to.geometry)
```

**[UPDATE]:** On Linux, os.environ['PROJ_DATA'] = /path/to/env/share/proj.  On Windows, there is no PROJ_DATA in os.environ.

---

Here is the output on **Windows**:

---

```
os name:  nt  
geopandas version:  0.12.2  
pyproj version:  3.4.1  
crs_from:  epsg:4269  
crs_to:  +proj=aea +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=23 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lon_0=-96 +no_defs +units=m +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +type=crs  

Environment variables include: ['PROJ_CURL_CA_BUNDLE']  
No PROJ_DATA in environment


Source geometry
0    MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.05100 42.81800, -74.04960 ...

Name: geometry, dtype: geometry


Target geometry
0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1768715.829 2407533.606, 17688...

Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

---

Here is the output on **Linux**:

---

```
os name:  posix  
geopandas version:  0.12.2  
pyproj version:  3.4.1  
crs_from:  epsg:4269  
crs_to:  +proj=aea +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=23 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lon_0=-96 +no_defs +units=m +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +type=crs  

Environment variables include: ['PROJ_DATA', 'PROJ_NETWORK', 'PROJ_CURL_CA_BUNDLE']  
PROJ_DATA = /home/wzell/mambaforge/envs/hyriver/share/proj


Source geometry
0    MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.05100 42.81800, -74.04960 ...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry


Target geometry
0    MULTIPOLYGON ((inf inf, inf inf, inf inf, inf inf, ...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

Comment: Have you had a look at your environment variables and if proj finds its resources? https://proj.org/usage/environmentvars.html

Comment: @user2856 Roger - edited and replaced screenshots with text.

Comment: @user2856 Thank you for testing that. I created a separate environment with those packages and versions and have some problem with 'inf's in output.

Comment: Sorry - that should read 'same problem' with **inf**s in output (I missed editing deadline).

Comment: @user2856 Thank you - I had checked the data but that's a good suggestion for isolating the behavior.  I substituted the shapefile read with the geojson construction (and updated my attempted code, above) and got same result with **inf**s in the output.

Comment: @user2856 That worked! Thank you for digging that up.  This was perhaps implied in the linked question but setting the environment variable `(os.environ['PROJ_NETWORK'] = 'OFF')` must be done before the pyproj and/or geopandas imports in the preamble.  Please advise how to accept your answer.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Windows and Linux behaving differently, it's something amiss in your Linux environment.  I'm running your script on Linux with no issues and get the correct output.  It may be that `proj` can't reach the internet to access the [transformation grids](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/transformation_grids.html) from your Linux device.

Try `os.environ['PROJ_NETWORK'] = 'OFF'` ala [First call to transform() fails with inf, all subsequent calls are OK - what could be the reason?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/373550/2856)

E.g.

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_NETWORK'] = 'OFF'

import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj

# rest of script...
```

Some other refs:

- https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/798
- https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1972
- https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/705